# Why MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen button icon change to caption icon in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I try to use MPMoviePlayerController as embedded video player but I spot a problem where the fullscreen icon were changed in iOS 10?

Is there any solution to change it back to original fullscreen button ?

Thank you,

This is what it look like in iOS 8 and iOS 9:

[image: This is what it look like in iOS 8 and iOS 9]

This is what it look like in iOS 10:

[image: This is what it look like in iOS 10]

Comment: Have you found any solution of this problem?

Comment: Nope, I end up update our target to ios 9 and switched to use AVPlayer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code to workaround that iOS 10 bug which you can write in a `WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug.m` file:

```
@import MediaPlayer;
@import ObjectiveC;

static void (*configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP)(id, SEL, BOOL);

static void ConfigureAuxiliaryButtons(id self, SEL _cmd, BOOL flag)
{
    configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP(self, _cmd, flag);
    @try
    {
        id delegate = [self delegate]; // Either nil or MPInlineVideoController (responds to `isFullscreen`) or MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController (does not respond to `isFullscreen`)
        BOOL isFullscreen = [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(isFullscreen)] ? [delegate isFullscreen] : YES;
        NSString *imageName = [@[ @"Video", @"Player", @"_", isFullscreen ? @"Exit" : @"Enter", @"Fullscreen" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        SEL imageNamedForControlState = NSSelectorFromString([@[ @"_", @"image", @"Named", @":", @"for", @"Control", @"State", @":" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
        UIImage *normalImage = ((UIImage *(*)(id, SEL, NSString *, UIControlState))objc_msgSend)(self, imageNamedForControlState, imageName, UIControlStateNormal);
        UIImage *highlightedImage = ((UIImage *(*)(id, SEL, NSString *, UIControlState))objc_msgSend)(self, imageNamedForControlState, imageName, UIControlStateHighlighted);
        UIButton *fullscreenButton = [self valueForKey:[@[ @"fullscreen", @"Button" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
        [fullscreenButton setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [fullscreenButton setImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug: %@", exception);
    }
}

void WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug(void)
{
    if (![NSProcessInfo.processInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){10, 0, 0}])
        return;

    Class MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView = NSClassFromString([@[ @"M", @"P", @"Video", @"Playback", @"Overlay", @"View" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
    SEL configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL = NSSelectorFromString([@[ @"_", @"configure", @"Auxiliary", @"Buttons", @":" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
    NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL];
    if (methodSignature.numberOfArguments != 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug (method not found)");
        return;
    }

    const char *returnType = methodSignature.methodReturnType;
    const char *argType = [methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2];
    if (strcmp(returnType, @encode(void)) != 0 || strcmp(argType, @encode(BOOL)) != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug (type mismatch)");
        return;
    }

    Method configureAuxiliaryButtons = class_getInstanceMethod(MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView, configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL);
    configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP = (__typeof__(configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP))method_getImplementation(configureAuxiliaryButtons);
    method_setImplementation(configureAuxiliaryButtons, (IMP)ConfigureAuxiliaryButtons);
}
```

Then update your `main.m` file to call the `WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug` function before running the `UIApplicationMain` function:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

extern void WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug();
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement this solution in a Swift project where there is no main.m file? I am having this same issue with the icon and yours is the only solution I've found for this.

Comment: Would Apple approve my app with this change?