# Change MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen button icon to caption icon in iOS in Swift Project

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, code-migration

I am using MPMoviePlayerController as an embedded video player, but the fullscreen icon from iOS 10+ has changed.

Original image in iOS 8, 9

[image]

Image in iOS 10+

[image]

I made the change earlier in an Objective-C project. Referring to this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012150/why-mpmovieplayercontroller-fullscreen-button-icon-change-to-caption-icon-in-ios). `WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug.m`

```
@import MediaPlayer;
@import ObjectiveC;

static void (*configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP)(id, SEL, BOOL);

static void ConfigureAuxiliaryButtons(id self, SEL _cmd, BOOL flag)
{
    configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP(self, _cmd, flag);
    @try
    {
        id delegate = [self delegate]; // Either nil or MPInlineVideoController (responds to `isFullscreen`) or MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController (does not respond to `isFullscreen`)
        BOOL isFullscreen = [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(isFullscreen)] ? [delegate isFullscreen] : YES;
        NSString *imageName = [@[ @"Video", @"Player", @"_", isFullscreen ? @"Exit" : @"Enter", @"Fullscreen" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        SEL imageNamedForControlState = NSSelectorFromString([@[ @"_", @"image", @"Named", @":", @"for", @"Control", @"State", @":" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
        UIImage *normalImage = ((UIImage *(*)(id, SEL, NSString *, UIControlState))objc_msgSend)(self, imageNamedForControlState, imageName, UIControlStateNormal);
        UIImage *highlightedImage = ((UIImage *(*)(id, SEL, NSString *, UIControlState))objc_msgSend)(self, imageNamedForControlState, imageName, UIControlStateHighlighted);
        UIButton *fullscreenButton = [self valueForKey:[@[ @"fullscreen", @"Button" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
        [fullscreenButton setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [fullscreenButton setImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug: %@", exception);
    }
}

void WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug(void)
{
    if (![NSProcessInfo.processInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){10, 0, 0}])
        return;

    Class MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView = NSClassFromString([@[ @"M", @"P", @"Video", @"Playback", @"Overlay", @"View" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
    SEL configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL = NSSelectorFromString([@[ @"_", @"configure", @"Auxiliary", @"Buttons", @":" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
    NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL];
    if (methodSignature.numberOfArguments != 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug (method not found)");
        return;
    }

    const char *returnType = methodSignature.methodReturnType;
    const char *argType = [methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2];
    if (strcmp(returnType, @encode(void)) != 0 || strcmp(argType, @encode(BOOL)) != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug (type mismatch)");
        return;
    }

    Method configureAuxiliaryButtons = class_getInstanceMethod(MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView, configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL);
    configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP = (__typeof__(configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP))method_getImplementation(configureAuxiliaryButtons);
    method_setImplementation(configureAuxiliaryButtons, (IMP)ConfigureAuxiliaryButtons);
}
```

And then calling it from the `main.m` function as

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

extern void WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug();
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The above solution worked fine, but in Swift, I am not sure how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Please show the relevant code in this question.

Comment: "I am using MPMoviePlayerController". Don't. It is deprecated. Use AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: @matt It is better not to, but I was still curious to find a solution to this problem in Swift.

Comment: Do not keep re-adding a nonsense tag when the community removes it. I’ve removed it again, do not re-create it, it is no better than the now-removed `swift-converter` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem has multiple stages. First, we need to add a main.m to our Swift so that the code in the original solution can be injected. In Swift projects the main file is abstracted. Refer to this [post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-subclass-uiapplication-using-uiapplicationmain).

So the first step is to remove `@UIApplicationMain` keyword from `AppDelegate` class.

Then we add a main.m by adding an Objective-C.m file and naming it as `main`
[image].

Add the following code as below in the `main.m` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MoviePlayerDemo-Swift.h"

extern void WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug();
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The original icon changing code remains the same as in the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210068/5807290):

```
@import MediaPlayer;
@import ObjectiveC;

static void (*configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP)(id, SEL, BOOL);

static void ConfigureAuxiliaryButtons(id self, SEL _cmd, BOOL flag)
{
    configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP(self, _cmd, flag);
    @try
    {
        id delegate = [self delegate]; // Either nil or MPInlineVideoController (responds to `isFullscreen`) or MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController (does not respond to `isFullscreen`)
        BOOL isFullscreen = [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(isFullscreen)] ? [delegate isFullscreen] : YES;
        NSString *imageName = [@[ @"Video", @"Player", @"_", isFullscreen ? @"Exit" : @"Enter", @"Fullscreen" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        SEL imageNamedForControlState = NSSelectorFromString([@[ @"_", @"image", @"Named", @":", @"for", @"Control", @"State", @":" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
        UIImage *normalImage = ((UIImage *(*)(id, SEL, NSString *, UIControlState))objc_msgSend)(self, imageNamedForControlState, imageName, UIControlStateNormal);
        UIImage *highlightedImage = ((UIImage *(*)(id, SEL, NSString *, UIControlState))objc_msgSend)(self, imageNamedForControlState, imageName, UIControlStateHighlighted);
        UIButton *fullscreenButton = [self valueForKey:[@[ @"fullscreen", @"Button" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
        [fullscreenButton setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [fullscreenButton setImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug: %@", exception);
    }
}

void WorkaroundInlinePlayerFullScreenButtonBug(void)
{
    if (![NSProcessInfo.processInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){10, 0, 0}])
        return;

    Class MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView = NSClassFromString([@[ @"M", @"P", @"Video", @"Playback", @"Overlay", @"View" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
    SEL configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL = NSSelectorFromString([@[ @"_", @"configure", @"Auxiliary", @"Buttons", @":" ] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
    NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL];
    if (methodSignature.numberOfArguments != 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug (method not found)");
        return;
    }

    const char *returnType = methodSignature.methodReturnType;
    const char *argType = [methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2];
    if (strcmp(returnType, @encode(void)) != 0 || strcmp(argType, @encode(BOOL)) != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to workaround inline player fullscreen button bug (type mismatch)");
        return;
    }

    Method configureAuxiliaryButtons = class_getInstanceMethod(MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView, configureAuxiliaryButtonsSEL);
    configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP = (__typeof__(configureAuxiliaryButtonsIMP))method_getImplementation(configureAuxiliaryButtons);
    method_setImplementation(configureAuxiliaryButtons, (IMP)ConfigureAuxiliaryButtons);
}
```